# Highcharts: Deselect all points within a series

Tags: highcharts

Alright, so I have a selection event that selects wanted points.
The problem I have is that it just adds on to the previously selected points. I was curious if there is an easy way to have all the points deselected with a function/library call without making a custom function that iterates through all the points?

**UPDATE:**
This is how I select my points. It is performed within the selection event.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.series.length; i++)    //Iterate through all the series on the chart
{
    if(this.series[i].selected)                 //If the series is selected in the legend
    {
        var points = this.series[i].points;   //Retrieve all points within this certain series that are visible
        var xs = event.xAxis[0];    //Get the xAxis size
        $.each(points, function (i,p) { //For all the points visible in the series
            if (p.x >= xs.min && p.x <= xs.max) {   //Boundary check the selected points
                p.select(true, true);   //Set the selected points to selected
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You would have to show us code on how you are selecting the points. There are many methods.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution to my problem. I added an else statement to the if that deselected any points that are not within the selected range. I plan to make the else into an else if (ctrl key is NOT pressed) for better functionality.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.series.length; i++)    //Iterate through all the series on the chart
{
    if(this.series[i].selected)                 //If the series is selected in the legend
    {
        var points = this.series[i].points;   //Retrieve all points within this certain series that are visible
        var xs = event.xAxis[0];    //Get the xAxis size
        $.each(points, function (i,p) { //For all the points visible in the series
            if (p.x >= xs.min && p.x <= xs.max) {   //Boundary check the selected points
                p.select(true, true);   //Set the selected points to selected
            }
            else
                p.select(false, true);  //Set points outside of boundary to deselected
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So, there is a function called `getSelectedPoints()`, then you have a array with all selected points. The next step is to deselect all these points with `select()`

Here the highcharts api: [getSelectedPoints()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#getSelectedPoints)
And the jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3xdm/)

Comment: This worked for me, only I shortened it to chart.getSelectedPoints()[0].select()
because I didn't need the alert. It seems more efficient than the OP's solution below.

Answer (score 1):

you should iterate over each serie of the chart and call hide or show function depending on what you want to do

```
i = 0;

while (i < chart.series.length) {
  if (chart.series[i].visible === false) {
    chart.series[i].select();
    chart.series[i].show();
    i++;
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the API docs on the [`select`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.select) method you are explicitly telly it to accumulate all the points selected to the new point you want selected. So, set your second param to `false`.

```
$.each(points, function (i,p) { //For all the points visible in the series
    if (p.x >= xs.min && p.x <= xs.max) {   //Boundary check the selected points
        p.select(true, false);   //Set the selected points to selected
    }
});
```

Comment: With the code I provided it accumulates all the points selected. If I set the second one to false it just makes it to where the last point selected is the only point selected. I may select multiple points at one time and this negates that. I was just curious if there was a function call that deslected any selected points.

Comment: Well if I can clear it before I select the new points then that would be perfect.

Comment: Confused here...This code does this "Well if I can clear it before I select the new points then that would be perfect." Each time you click on a new point all other points are deselected and only the clicked point is selected. If you want it to know that the user wants to do multi-select vs single select you can use the mouse click state (ctrl-click, shift-click, etc) to determine which selection code to use.

Comment: The code I supplied handles multi-point selection. So when I set it as p.select(true, false) it only selects one point and ignores the other points that may have been selected. I'm just trying to be able to clear all points selected before I select a new set of (multiple)points.

Comment: How would the code know you want to select multiple? When does it stop adding the newly selected point to the list of selected = true? I would recommend adding a button of some sort to clear selections. Then, when that button is clicked it cycles through all series like you have now but it does `p.select(false, false);`. Then you can select a new set of points.

Comment: I'll probably design a function to perform that very action and have it run before the selection event unless the 'ctrl' button is selected.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript:

```
  /**
   * Deselect all the points on all series
   */
  private deselectAllPoints() {
    const series = chart.series;
    series.forEach(s => {
      s.data.forEach((point: Point) => {
        point.select(false);
      });
    });
  }
```

Or just plain JavaScript:

```
    chart.series.forEach(s => {
      s.data.forEach((point) => {
        point.select(false);
      });
    });
```